# Select query INNER JOIN issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tow tables `Requisitions` and `RequisitionDetails`

Requisitions table

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| RequisitionID | RequisitionDate |
+---------------+-----------------+
|             1 | 2016-08-17      |
|             2 | 2016-08-18      |
|             3 | 2016-08-19      |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

RequisitionDetails table

```
+---------------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------------+
| RequisitionDetailID | RequisitionID | ItemID | Quantity | ReceivedQuantity |
+---------------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------------+
|                   1 |             1 |      1 |        2 |                1 |
|                   2 |             1 |      2 |        3 |                2 |
|                   3 |             2 |      3 |        4 |                3 |
+---------------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------------+
```

I am trying to get Requisition data where Quantity is not equal to ReceivedQuantity.

i have tried the below query but its record with RequisitionID `1` twice.

How can i make the query returns the Requisition data without repeating the requisition data based on items that have Quantity is not equal to ReceivedQuantity.

```
SELECT
  dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID,
  dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionDate
FROM dbo.Requisitions
INNER JOIN dbo.RequisitionDetails
  ON dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID = dbo.RequisitionDetails.RequisitionID
where dbo.RequisitionDetails.Quantity != dbo.RequisitionDetails.ReceivedQuantity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning twice because of the two rows with `RequistionID = 1` in the `RequistionDetails` table.  Since the rows returned are exact duplicates you can simply add the `DISTINCT` keyword to your select to see one of them:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID,
dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionDate
FROM dbo.Requisitions
INNER JOIN dbo.RequisitionDetails
ON dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID = dbo.RequisitionDetails.RequisitionID
where   dbo.RequisitionDetails.Quantity!=
dbo.RequisitionDetails.ReceivedQuantity
```

You should also use some aliases to clean up your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
           R.RequisitionID,
           R.RequisitionDate
FROM       dbo.Requisitions R
INNER JOIN dbo.RequisitionDetails RD ON R.RequisitionID = RD.RequisitionID
WHERE      RD.Quantity != RD.ReceivedQuantity
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can use exists for your case

```
select 
* from requistions rq where exists(
select 1 from RequisitionDetails  rd where rd.RequisitionID=rq.RequisitionID
and rd.Quantity!=rd.ReceivedQuantity)
```

Answer (score 2):

As you don't need columns from the 2nd table you can also switch to `EXISTS` to avoid `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT req.*
FROM dbo.Requisitions as req
WHERE EXISTS
 ( SELECT * FROM dbo.RequisitionDetails as req_det
    WHERE req.RequisitionID = req_det.RequisitionID
      AND Quantity <> ReceivedQuantity
 )
```

Or `IN`:

```
SELECT req.*
FROM dbo.Requisitions
WHERE RequisitionID IN
 ( SELECT RequisitionID
   FROM dbo.RequisitionDetails
    WHERE Quantity <> ReceivedQuantity
 )
```